# Getting constant usbmuxd errors on Console in El Capitan ( MB Pro Early 2011 )

Tags: usb, ipad

When I connect my iPad Air, I'm getting constant erros like these:

```
22.10.2015 09:37:54,599 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: HandleUSBMuxDictionary client 0x7f848aa06e20-duet/NULL using library 1.4.0, running usbmuxd-364
22.10.2015 09:37:56,602 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: HandleUSBMuxDictionary client 0x7f848a809590-duet/NULL using library 1.4.0, running usbmuxd-364
22.10.2015 09:37:56,603 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: MuxTCPInputSCE received RST for 0xb2-7bd2b4726ba0e964d43439d050e1ff5242dd0729@0xfd120000:2345->0x7f848a809590-duet/NULL:23870: handleConnectResult: failure - 61
22.10.2015 09:37:57,859 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: HandleUSBMuxDictionary client 0x7f8488f00c30-duet/NULL using library 1.4.0, running usbmuxd-364
22.10.2015 09:37:58,861 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: HandleUSBMuxDictionary client 0x7f8488e07480-duet/NULL using library 1.4.0, running usbmuxd-364
22.10.2015 09:37:58,862 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: MuxTCPInputSCE received RST for 0xb2-7bd2b4726ba0e964d43439d050e1ff5242dd0729@0xfd120000:2345->0x7f8488e07480-duet/NULL:24126: handleConnectResult: failure - 61
22.10.2015 09:38:00,119 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: HandleUSBMuxDictionary client 0x7f848a809590-duet/NULL using library 1.4.0, running usbmuxd-364
22.10.2015 09:38:01,121 com.apple.usbmuxd[84]: HandleUSBMuxDictionary client 0x7f8488f030c0-duet/NULL using library 1.4.0, running usbmuxd-364
```

When I disconnect, these errors disappear. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that while my Mac has Duet app installed my iPad has no longer this app installed and I think this causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the errors streaming constantly when nothing was plugged into USB at all. so bad that the disk was constantly churning and every activity generated beachballs.   Just quit Duet and the errors stopped and the disk has calmed down, beach ball season has ended.  All this time, an app I never used.